# Separa resultado dentro do each

Tags: jquery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Possuo uma função ajax onde leio os dados dentro de um $.each() , a imagem acima contem o resultado deste each.
Estou tentando dentro deste mesmo each separar em dois arrays os dados que coincidirem entre pergunta e gráfico, pois irei gerar neste caso dois gráficos contendo os dados, um sobre a pergunta1 e gráfico Column e outro com os dados da pergunta2 e gráfico Bar.

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: já tentou usar um if dentro do $.each?

Comment: ja pensei nisso mas ocorre que o valor dentro de pergunta é dinamico, ou seja em um momento {pergunta:"você está empregado",resposta:"Sim"} seraá diferente do print por isso não fiz um if, mas tens alguma sugestão de como fazer sem estipular uma string fixa no if?

Comment: Não. Falo do if só da coluna grafico, por exemplo: `if( j.grafico == 'Column' )` ou do Bar

Comment: @adventistaam , obrigado pela ajuda ! vou agregar com if´s as demais opções de gráficos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, criando as duas novas arrays e fazendo o `.push` dentro do `.each`. No exemplo abaixo você só precisa alterar as variáveis de acordo com as que você usa no seu código:

```js
var array_original = []; // array original, resultado do each
var array_col = []; // nova array com pergunta1 e Column
var array_bar = []; // nova array com pergunta2 e Bar


$.each($("div"), function(i,e){
   
   var dataPergunta = $(e).data("pergunta");
   var dataGrafico = $(e).data("grafico");
   
   array_original.push({
      "pergunta" : dataPergunta,
      "resposta" : $(e).data("resposta"),
      "grafico" : dataGrafico,
      "qt" : $(e).data("qt").toString()
   });
   
   // adiciona às novas arrays
   var novaArray;
   if(dataPergunta == "pergunta1" && dataGrafico == "Column"){
      novaArray = array_col;
   }else if(dataPergunta == "pergunta2" && dataGrafico == "Bar"){
      novaArray = array_bar;
   }

   if(novaArray){
      novaArray.push({
         "pergunta" : dataPergunta,
         "resposta" : $(e).data("resposta"),
         "grafico" : dataGrafico,
         "qt" : $(e).data("qt").toString()
      });
   }
});

console.log("Original", array_original);
console.log("Column", array_col);
console.log("Bar", array_bar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-pergunta="pergunta1" data-resposta="item1" data-grafico="Column" data-qt="3">1</div>
<div data-pergunta="pergunta1" data-resposta="item2" data-grafico="Column" data-qt="2">2</div>
<div data-pergunta="pergunta2" data-resposta="item1" data-grafico="Bar" data-qt="1">3</div>
<div data-pergunta="pergunta2" data-resposta="item2" data-grafico="Bar" data-qt="1">4</div>
<div data-pergunta="pergunta2" data-resposta="item3" data-grafico="Bar" data-qt="3">5</div>
<div data-pergunta="pergunta3" data-resposta="item3" data-grafico="Bar" data-qt="3">6</div>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente! Muito Obrigado !!

Answer (score 0):

Como os dados são dinâmicos você pode filtrar apenas da coluna do gráfico como no exemplo:

```js
var original = [
  {pergunta: "pergunta1", resposta: "item1", grafico: "Column", qt: "3"},
  {pergunta: "pergunta1", resposta: "item2", grafico: "Column", qt: "2"},
  {pergunta: "pergunta2", resposta: "item1", grafico: "Bar", qt: "1"},
  {pergunta: "pergunta2", resposta: "item2", grafico: "Bar", qt: "1"},
  {pergunta: "pergunta2", resposta: "item3", grafico: "Bar", qt: "3"},
]

var column = []
var bar    = []
var divColumn = "Column <br>";
var divBar = "Bar <br>";
$.each( original, function(i, j){
    if( j.grafico === 'Bar' ){
      divBar += JSON.stringify( original[i] )+"<br>";
      bar.push(
           original[i]
       )
    }else{
     divColumn += JSON.stringify( original[i] )+"<br>";
     column.push( original[i] )
    }
} )
console.log( bar ) 
console.log( column ) 
$('.bar').append( divBar )
$('.bar').append( divColumn )
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
```